# Should a verb in the phrase "A family of animals" be singular or plural?

Tags: collective-nouns

> A family of rabbits **is** playing in the garden.

Here can I use **are** instead of **is**? According to Combridge dictionary, is or are is correct here, right?
[C, + sing/pl verb]: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/family

Comment: Tell me, where have you seen this used?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, "is" is correct because "family" is a *collective term*. "A family" is singular. 'Rabbits' is plural, but this is just acting as an attributive noun - "a family of rabbits" is essentially the same as saying "a rabbit family".

- Rabbits *are* playing in the garden
- A family *is* playing in the garden.

The exception you refer to in British English is that collective nouns are sometimes treated as plurals, but this depends on the context and the emphasis you want to make. If the emphasis is on the collective being *singular of purpose*, it tends to be singular, for example, "the government **is** backing the proposal" suggests that 'the government' (a group of people) is 'of one mind', behind a proposal. On the other hand, in British English it is allowable to use collectives as a plural, and this can emphasise the individuality of the members, for example "the government *are* currently debating the issue" emphasises that, in a debate or discussion, individuals may put exchange differing points of view.

Comment: But in the Combridge dictionary, its usage is described as follow: [+ sing/pl verb]: A noun that refers to a group of people acting collectively. When used in the singular it can be followed by either a singular or a plural verb in British English. In American English a singular verb is preferred.

Comment: American English requires the singular verb to be used -- you can't get by with a **family of rabbits are** here.

Comment: Could you tell me if a plural verb can be used in British English according to the Combridge dictionary?

Comment: @jones understood. I've updated the answer. I don't think your example was very well suited to using 'are' in British English so I've added in what I consider a better one.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely clear. Also, I'd like to quote another sentence from the Combridge dictionary: A new family has/have moved in next door.

Comment: @Jones Cambridge is a respectable English dictionary, and my BrEng dictionary of choice. It is absolutely correct, you could use either. If you have to make a choice, consider what you want to emphasise - their collective nature as a family, or the individuality of its members. If you don't think about it and say either, British speakers won't consider it wrong.